# Who invokes MyLogger.Log?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am attempting to trace how `MyLogger.Log` gets invoked whenever I invoke the extension method `logger.LogError("message");` as follows.

```
class MyLogger : ILogger
{
   // others have been removed for the sake of simplicity

   public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, 
       Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
   { 
        string str = $"{formatter(state, exception)}";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main1(string[] args)
   {    
    // others have been removed for simplicity.
    // ILogger<Program> logger = ....
    logger.LogError("the cpu is overheating");

   }
}
```

I can only trace up to the following extension method in `LoggerExtension` class:

```
public static void Log(this ILogger logger, LogLevel logLevel, string message, params object[] args)
{
   logger.Log(logLevel, 0, null, message, args);
}
```

using "F12" of Visual Studio to navigate to its definition. However,  `logger.Log(logLevel, 0, null, message, args);` does not match `MyLogger.Log` signature so there must be another method that invokes `MyLogger.Log`.

I have looked up at github but it is confusing. What is that method?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs#L283)?

Comment: Then I guess you're looking for [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/2.2/src/Logging/Logging.Abstractions/src/LoggerExtensions.cs#L396).

Comment: @KirkLarkin: I think so. Thank you very much. What should I do? Delete this question?

Comment: No, either you or @KirkLarkin should post that as answer probably with some good description

Comment: @Rahul: OK. I am waiting for him to submit the answer first. No need to hurry.